# select image tags with jquery

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am very new to jquery. I want to apply this jquery to all images in wordpress. I don't know how to use this code with below code.

```
$('a[href$=jpg], a[href$=JPG], a[href$=jpeg], a[href$=JPEG], a[href$=png], a[href$=gif], a[href$=bmp]:has(img)')
```

How can I integrate upper code to this code? Now I need to add .sb class to all images manually but it doesn't make sense.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.sb').click(function(event){
    // which was clicked?
    var clicked = $(this).index('.sb');

    // create smoothbox
   $('body').append('<div class="smoothbox sb-load"><div class="smoothbox-table"><div class="smoothbox-centering"><div class="smoothbox-sizing"><div class="sb-nav"><a href="#" class="sb-prev sb-prev-on" alt="Previous">&larr;</a><a href="#" class="sb-cancel" alt="Close">&times;</a><a href="#" class="sb-next sb-next-on" alt="Next">&rarr;</a></div><ul class="sb-items"></ul></div></div></div></div>');

    $.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
    // get each picture, put them in the box
    $('.sb').reverse().each(function() {
       var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if ($(this).attr('title')) {
            var caption = $(this).attr('title');
            $('.sb-items').append('<div class="sb-item"><div class="sb-caption">'+ caption +'</div><img src="'+ href + '"/></div>');
        }   
        else {
              $('.sb-items').append('<div class="sb-item"><img src="'+ href + '"/></div>');

       }
    });

    $('.sb-item').slice(0,-(clicked)).appendTo('.sb-items');
    $('.sb-item').not(':last').hide();
    $('.sb-item img:last').load(function() { 
        $('.smoothbox-sizing').fadeIn('slow', function() {
            $('.sb-nav').fadeIn();
            $('.sb-load').removeClass('sb-load');
        });
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});

$(document).on('click', ".sb-cancel", function(event){
    $('.smoothbox').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('.smoothbox').remove();
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});

$(document).on('click', ".sb-next-on", function(event){
    $(this).removeClass('sb-next-on');

        $('.sb-item:last').addClass('sb-item-ani');
    // after animation, move order & remove class

        $(".sb-item:last").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){
            $('.sb-item').eq(-2).addClass('no-trans').fadeIn('fast');
            $(this).removeClass('sb-item-ani').prependTo('.sb-items').hide();
            $('.sb-item:last').removeClass('no-trans');
            $('.sb-next').addClass('sb-next-on');
            $('.sb-item').unbind();
        }); 

    event.preventDefault();
});

$(document).on('click', ".sb-prev-on", function(event){  
    $(this).removeClass('sb-prev-on');
        $('.sb-item:last').hide(); 
        $(".sb-item:first").addClass('sb-item-ani2 no-trans').appendTo('.sb-items');
        $('.sb-item:last').show().removeClass('no-trans').delay(1).queue(function(next){
            $('.sb-item:last').removeClass('sb-item-ani2');
            next();
        });
        $(this).addClass('sb-prev-on');           
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

});

Comment: Show your HTML. Can't you use `$('a[href$=jpg], a[href$=JPG], a[href$=jpeg], a[href$=JPEG], a[href$=png], a[href$=gif], a[href$=bmp]').find('img').addClass('sb')`?

Comment: What do you mean by *"integrate upper code to this code"*?? what does the later code do? What do you want to achieve by modifying it by making use of the former selector??